# Pandas not replacing character in large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When I create a small test dataframe this code works fine, but when attempting to use it after importing a large excel file it is not substituting the character.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                    'B':[4,5,6],
                    'C':['`f;','d:','sda`sd'],
                    'D':['s','d;','d;p`'],
                    'E':[5,3,6],
                    'F':[7,4,3]})
df.replace({'`':''}, regex=True)
```

The results are as expected:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   4   f;  s   5   7
1   2   5   d:  d;  3   4
2   3   6   sdasd   d;p 6   3
```

However when I load up a large excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
excel_file = f'C:\testfile.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name='Details', dtype=str)
df.iloc[20831].loc['Group Number']
```

Result:

```
'008513L-0005 `'
```

Then run the replace:

```
df.replace({'`':''}, regex=True)
df.iloc[20831].loc['Group Number']
```

Result:

```
'008513L-0005 `'
```

Comment: You're not assigning the result of the replacemant back to the dataframe, or using `inplace=True`

Comment: To add on to @G.Anderson's answer, to assign the result back, you simply need to do something like this `df=df.replace({'\`':''}, regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the problem you encounter in Natural Language Processing Methods with the "string punctuation" function.

```
import string #We have defined the string library.
def remove_punctuation (text): #We form our function.
    no_punc = "".join([i for i in text if i not in string.punctuation])
    return no_punc
#We apply our function to the corresponding column of our data set.
df['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: remove_punctuation (x))
df['D'] = df['D'].apply(lambda x: remove_punctuation (x))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSrmG.png)